# Importing Typescript as a file structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tsconfig

I'm encountering problems while trying to type-check and start my code, stating "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module". The error is being cause when I'm importing a "module" into my main index file to initiate some code. Within that file there are some more imports of the same nature and functions which perform actions outside of a class. I'm not creating a class within that file so there is nothing to export, hence importing the whole file.

An end result would be that I compile the index file which simply imports the others to create one big compiled file. Here is the entire error as displayed in the console:

```
/opt/srv/resources/core/server/index.js:2
server  | import './core/server.js';
server  | ^^^^^^
server  | 
server  | SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
server  |     at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:74:18)
server  |     at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:20)
server  |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1182:27)
server  |     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
server  |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
server  |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
server  |     at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:169:29)
server  |     at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)
```

After following many guides and applying different suggestions, such as configuring my package.json as type - module and changing the tsconfig to compile as ESNext and NodeNext etc. I've not made any progress on this issue and it's becoming a real blocker. Annoyingly each configuration that I've tried, nothing seems to change the outcome and it compiles with this error all of the time.

Help is extremely appreciated.

Here is the file structure I am using:

```
├─ tsconfig.json
└─ src/
   ├─ client/
   ├─ shared/
   └─ server/
      ├─ core/
      │  ├─ server.ts (imported file)
      │  └─ other.ts (another imported file)
      └─ index.ts (main file)
```

Here is the index file - It simply contains an import for the server.ts file which will later be compiled into a js file (hence importing a .js version)

```
import './core/server.js';
```

Here is the server.ts file which contains some imports and

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

console.log(`Script has been started`);

const prisma = new PrismaClient(arguments...);
prisma.$connect();

console.log(`Prisma connected, counting accounts - ${prisma.accounts.count()}`);

etc...
```

Comment: I would use a target of "ES6" if not something newer; "ESNext" depends on your Typescript version, and you definitely want at least ES6.

Comment: Ah okay, I changed that but still the same result, unfortunately.

Comment: Well I'm far from a Node expert and even less Typescript, but generally I name all my JavaScript modules with the ".mjs" extension. That makes them modules without having to fiddle with `package.json`.